# Add Pagination To Catalog Search Results REST API: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am using this API for search:

> [http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=life](http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria%5BrequestName%5D=quick_search_container&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=search_term&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=life)

The response is:

**- Total results is 7**

I need to get results in pagination mode so I updated the API to become:

> [http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=life&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[page_size]=5](http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria%5BrequestName%5D=quick_search_container&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=search_term&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=life&searchCriteria%5Bcurrent_page%5D=1&searchCriteria%5Bpage_size%5D=5)

The response is:

**- Total results is 5**

**- Current page is 1**

If I changed the current page 2, the response supposed to be:

-**Total results is 2**

**- Current page is 2**

But, I got the same result in the page 1.

Comment: This is a long-term Magento bug since 2.0.X https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8099

Answer (score 2):

> rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0]
>   [field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0]
>   [value]=7&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0]
>   [conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0]
>   [field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1&searchCriteria[currentPage]=4